# Restrict a function to only get called with "new" operator

Tags: javascript

```
var Test = function () {
    console.log("something");
}
```

I want to call this function only by putting "new" i.e new Test(); 
It should throw error when called in this way. Test();

Comment: just take the demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target

Answer (score 0):

The `new.target` property lets you detect whether a function or constructor was called using the `new` operator. In constructors and functions instantiated with the new operator, `new.target` returns a reference to the constructor or function. In normal function calls, `new.target` is undefined. (shamelessly copied from MDN)

```
var Test = function () {
    if (!new.target) throw 'Test() must be called with new';
    console.log("something");
}
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target

Comment: Please add some comments to your answer to explain your code!